# Why is this program getting a segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
int main() 
{
    char *d = "1234";

    char *p = d;
    p = p+2;
    p[0] = '2';    \\Error line

    printf("%s", p);
}
```

If i remove the line "Error line" then there is no seg fault. Whats the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying constant memory.  Even though you don't have the `const` keyword, the type of `"1234"` is `const char *`.

Answer (score 0):

What pointers *d and *p point are read-only data. (Text segment). Trying to modify it cause error.

You could fix it by:

```
    /* Using character arrary, initialized it with "1234" */

    char d[] = "1234";
```

or

```
    /* Malloc heap memory for"1234" */

    char *d = (char *)malloc(4); 
    strcpy(d, "1234");
    // ...
    free(d);
```

You should also add one extra space for the terminal character "\0".

Comment: So when i use ' char d[] = "1234" ', the array d is in **data segment**, am i right?

Comment: C does not specify nor does it care where such data is stored. It *does* specify that you should not modify constant data.